# Animate Excavator digging

Tags: animation

I want to animate an excavator and the path he makes in the ground while digging in an abstract way. Animating the excavator seems to be no problem but I have trouble with animating the ground cause the shovel is entering it in a radial way. 
I used the AnimAll add on to Animate the vertices of the ground to create the digging process but it is a very unsatisfying way.

I hope you have a better idea! 
[Some pictures regarding my problem](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/l6yya2g3bbly2kp/AABe3iDjMuUYVTQD-A2W6260a?dl=0)

Thank you in advance

Fabian

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and use the tools from this site to upload images so that they appear as part of your question. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Answer (score 2):

The Boolean Modifier will come in handy here. It's not a physically accurate solution, but you can certainly fake it for illustration purposes.

[image]

Boolean can carve out geometry based on a reference object. So in this case, you can create a transparent object to point the modifier to, which will do the carving. Parent it to your solid object so they move in sync.

I've made a demo file with a basic animation. You can [download it here.](https://mega.nz/#!YAcRCaTa!VupPRWShS31NACJ75E5Xrv1dIuHllCtdjewJhYCFKMY)